# Identifying SMD Resistor with a code that contains a colon

Tags: resistors, surface-mount

[image: Unknown SMD resistors]

What are the blue components seemingly labeled "69:1" in the attached image?
There is reason to believe that they are resistors, but of what value?

I thought perhaps the ":" is a "00" written on top of each other - but I couldn't find a 5 digit SMD resistor coding convention.

Comment: The AD829 is a 100+ MHz video amplifier. The components are likely some inductors, or specialized band-pass ceramic filters. Some reverse engineering of schematics would help here.

Comment: What reason do you have to believe they are resistors? The package?

Comment: Slap an ohm meter on them and report your findings

Comment: Try 6980 ohm, 1% tolerance.

Comment: @glen_geek Unsoldered them and measured - 6960 Ohm and 6970 Ohm. 
Now the question just seems silly. How do we mark this as resolved?

Comment: **Not** silly. A great example of cognitive illusion. Once your brain decides what it sees, it is very hard to un-see. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_Dancer

Comment: @BerryPi You can always answer or delete your own questions if you find a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments, the assumed colon was actually an 8.

SMD component was a resistor with value code 6981 (6980 ohm).

Comment: Answer posted per [meta thread recommendations.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5702/179725)